# Gitlab doesn't output terragrunt command

Tags: terraform, gitlab

Gitlab seems to just skip Terragrunt command.
I have tried other commands like `ls -la` or even a `bugous` command and they all behave as expected. Only `terragrunt` commands that seems to get completely ignored

here's part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
plan:
    stage: plan_dev
    parallel:
        matrix:
            - WORKLOAD_NAME:
                - workload-test
    script: | 
        aws sts get-caller-identity  << FOR TESTING MY SANITY
        cd ./accounts/workload_accounts/$WORKLOAD_NAME/non_prod
        export TF_LOG=TRACE
        terragrunt run-all foo-fail  << NOTICE TYPO
```

I expected an error, but Gitlab simply ignored it...

Output:

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity # collapsed multi-line command
{
    "UserId": "THINGTHING:i-THINGTHING",
    "Account": "12345678901",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::------------:------------"
}
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables

Job succeeded
```

It clearly should not succeeded, also I expect to see the error in the console.
I imagine there's some buffer or whatever, but I'm struggling to find any information.

Help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually in my GitLab agent. We build our own images to be used by the gitlab agent, and the script we use for installing terragrunt was installing an incompatible architecture version.

It was using the binary for **AMD64** while it should have been using **ARM64**

Here's the **WRONG** version of the terragrunt instalation in our Ubuntu 22 image:

```
# Make sure we have a version to install:
TERRAGRUNT_VERSION=$1
if [ "Z${TERRAGRUNT_VERSION}" = "Z" ]; then
    TERRAGRUNT_VERSION="0.53.5"
fi

# Download and install:
curl "https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v${TERRAGRUNT_VERSION}/terragrunt_linux_amd64" -o "terragrunt"
chmod +x terragrunt
mv terragrunt /usr/local/bin/terragrunt

# When running check it would already hang
/usr/local/bin/terragrunt --version
```

The new version checks for the right architecture:

```
# Make sure we have a version to install:
TERRAGRUNT_VERSION=$1
if [ "Z${TERRAGRUNT_VERSION}" = "Z" ]; then
    echo "No terragrunt version specified, using 0.53.5"
    TERRAGRUNT_VERSION="0.53.5"
fi

# Check architecture and download the appropriate binary:
case `uname -m` in \
        x86_64) ARCH=amd64; ;; \
        armv7l) ARCH=arm; ;; \
        aarch64) ARCH=arm64; ;; \
        ppc64le) ARCH=ppc64le; ;; \
        s390x) ARCH=s390x; ;; \
        *) echo "Unsupported architecture, exiting..."; exit 1; ;; \
    esac
TERRAGRUNT_URL="https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/releases/download/v${TERRAGRUNT_VERSION}/terragrunt_linux_${ARCH}"

wget -q "${TERRAGRUNT_URL}" -O /usr/local/bin/terragrunt
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/terragrunt

# Check if the installation was successful:
terragrunt -v
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not seeing the logs being shown as expected because you're using a multi-line command and GitLab collapses the result and shows just a small part of it. It is mentioned in the output you're seeing too:

`$ aws sts get-caller-identity # collapsed multi-line command <--`

This behaviour is the default one for the GitLab CI terminal, see [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3392#note_368568570) for more details. In this same thread it is suggested to use `set -xv` as a stop-gap solution.

Another option would be breaking down the script into multiple separate lines, as it doesn't seem that you are using any sort of logic operations within bash that would strictly require them to be within the same block. The updated version would be:

```yaml
plan:
    stage: plan_dev
    parallel:
        matrix:
            - WORKLOAD_NAME:
                - workload-test
    script:
        - aws sts get-caller-identity  << FOR TESTING MY SANITY
        - cd ./accounts/workload_accounts/$WORKLOAD_NAME/non_prod
        - export TF_LOG=TRACE
        - terragrunt run-all foo-fail  << NOTICE TYPO
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, multi-line commands do not behave as you mentioned. It does collapse the command only and `set -x` will "echo" each command line after `set`.  For that reason, I believe your answer is a bit misleading, so the reason I'm downvoting it.

The problem was actually in the image my GitLab agent was using. I'll post the answer here for reference.

Comment: Well the provided solution has nothing to do with the issue you were mentioning, as the base image was never mentioned and it was implied that the `script` part was failing so it was kinda hard to guess that. And as the linked issue mentions, multi-line command's log cannot be un-collapsed not allowing for a proper debugging

Comment: Indeed at the time of writing the question, I did not know the base image was the issue, which could also be the case of many others falling into the same "trap".    I did not downvote because it was not the answer I was looking for, My bad if this was your interpretation.
However the command behavior "set -x" that you explained is not correct. set -x is used to explicitly print the command input. Even when using multiline commands the output is still shown